# angular2: style generated has different attribute with the tag than that of attribute generated in html

Tags: angular

Has anyone come across this issue, I am attaching the url of gif ([gyazo.com/a187d40a4765d2d80e0ee617986fa1db](http://gyazo.com/a187d40a4765d2d80e0ee617986fa1db)) which shows that I have a component 'my-server' and I have added a tag selector in server.component.css as follow:

```
my-server {
  display: block
}
```

but when angular2 generates style it makes it

```
my-server[_ngcontent-c2] {
  display: block
}
```

The main problem is the generated dom does have some other attributes
_ngcontent-c1 as below

```
<my-server _ngcontent-c1></my-server>
```

and hence my style is not getting applied to component tag level

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a187d40a4765d2d80e0ee617986fa1db   plz check this url here is gif.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to not apply any CSS directly on a component. Instead of doing that use a DIV as first child of component and apply your CSS to that Div.

```
      <my-server>
         <div class="your-class">
             <!--Write your component code here-->
         </div>
      </my-server>
```

Angular components do not belong to the default html elements, so it may be the reason of not applying your CSS.